# Thousands of async Tasks, await task.delay() issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I use a loop to start ~1000-2000 tasks, usually at a rate of about 1 task per second. To create the tasks i simply do something like:

```
For i = 0 to 2000
    Task.run(
        Async Function()
            Await RunHttpLoop()
        End Function)
    await task.delay(1000)
Next
```

Now, the RunHttpLoop() looks something like this:

```
Async Function RunHttpLoop()
    dim response = Await webclient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(someuri)
    if response.contains("finished") then return

    dim startsleep = datetime.now
    await task.delay(1000)

    'Measure how much longer than 1000ms each task slept
    console.writeline((startsleep - datetime.now).duration.totalmilliseconds - 1000)) 
End Function
```

I'm creating a bunch of tasks which should be asynchronously downloading data from some sources.

Now, the problem. While i still have a small number of tasks, everything works fine. As i start getting more tasks, i periodically get moments where the tasks that are sleeping (await task.delay(1000)), simply stop waking up on time. For a few seconds (2-3 seconds) not a single task will wake up. It will seem like they're just frozen. Then suddenly they all wake up in one giant burst.

I measure the time each task slept, subtract from it 1000 (expected sleep time) and i get the "deviation" of sleep, usually ~15ms. I out put this to console as soon as the task wakes up:

```
Task sleep deviation from 1000ms:
0
15
13
12
5
15
14
3
9
5
8
51
22
11
15 <----Freezes here for ~2-3 seconds


...Nothing...


1000 <---GIANT burst of delayed tasks comes rushing out
2000
500
600
900
1200
1500 
1200
900
1200
1500
1200
600
900
1200
1500 
1200
900
1200
1500
1200
15 <-----Back to normal.
10
6
11
7
15
10
6
11
7
...etc
```

This cycle repeats very periodically every ~10 seconds.
Here are some images.
Normal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMWdW.png
Burst of late tasks waking up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLM3q.png

Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably look into `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` when you create your tasks. This will free them from the scheduler (at the cost of the generation of more threads).

Comment: What happens *after* a call to await happens at some unspecified and non-deterministic time after the task finishes running. You should never assume this is immediate. This is part of the programming model. When you're using async you're basically saying you don't care when it runs, or on what thread it runs, as long as it doesn't start too early.

Comment: Fantastic questions, thanks for providing useful data! 1000ms delays certainly are unexpected and not due to OS scheduling decisions. How many threads are in the app process right after a latency burst happened? How much RAM does the box have?

Comment: I'm thinking about Timer Coalescing. I cannot imagine that it would cause such delays but let's check. What power plan is the server on and does the problem go away if you put it into high performance mode? This is a really weak hunch...

Comment: Please post a minimal repro. I'm wondering if it has to do with HTTP throttling (request and/or server-side), since I'm unable to repro with [this code](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/3890e57c0e83c4f0dc12).

Comment: Did you try to mock the http request? Most chances are that the bottleneck is the number of connections. Try to replace RunHttpLoop() with Task.Delay(300).